# Administratively putting users into groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, grouping

There are many users and one administrator. Users can create groups and send/receive requests to join those groups. That system works fine. I am now building separate "super groups" that the admin creates. These "super groups" don't rely on requests, they rely on appointment. The admin selects a user, selects a group, and adds the chosen user into the chosen group. How do I accomplish this?

- How do I set it up so that the admin can simply pick a user(on their profile page), pick a group(preferably from a drop-down) and then make the association?

For example, as an admin, I would like to go to the user's profile page and on the profile page there is a drop-down(only admin-accessible) and add the user to the group of my choice. How would I accomplish this? Through a type of form? A boolean field? Could I just add an append method (<<) into my join model create action and have a select-tag for a group and then a create-submit button? I just need to be pointed in the general direction and I think that I can manage.

**Of note:** I am using a has_many :through association to capture the relationship. An admin has many "super groups" which are created/deleted fine. The "super group" has many members(users). I just need to know how to put users into a group administratively.

Comment: How many models are these split between? Do you have a `SuperGroup` model and a `Group` model, or is a `SuperGroup` just a type of `Group`? If you could include these models with their associations, that would be helpful to suggest a solution for you.

Comment: Groups and Super Groups are two separate models.

Comment: I really just need to know best practice for adding a user to a has_many :through association via dropdown.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Short answer is: Use the dropdown to select a `super_group_id`. Pass that to Rails controller. Use the append method (`<<`) to assign user to group once you've loaded the correct records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE - What is the best practice for adding a user to a has_many :through association via dropdown?**

You are talking about wanting to add a user to a super group FROM the user's profile page. This means you want to pass a `super_group_id` to the Rails controller, find that super group, and then add the user to that group.

This is one option:

```
 @user = User.find(params[:id]) # or user_id, depending on the controller
 @super_group = SuperGroup.find(params[:super_group_id])
 @super_group.users << @user
```

**Original Answer:**

How are you currently creating and deleting the Super Groups? I assume you have a `SuperGroupsController`. One way to accomplish this is to have a sub-controller `SuperGroups::UsersController` with your same RESTful actions (`create`, `update`, etc). Those restful actions handle the assigning/removing of the users to groups. This allows you to separate the checking that you need to do to make sure only an admin is taking these actions.

```
class SuperGroups::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :verify_admin # create this method to do the checking

  def create
    # create a user super group association here
  end

  def delete
    # remove a user from the super group here
  end
end
```

This is apparently a best practice according to DHH. I first used this method after reading [this article](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/) and I've found this pattern very clean and useful.

Comment: I have a Super Group Association controller that creates and deletes the super groups' memberships. I basically have what you described, currently. What I'm lost on is how to select a user to add into the association. For example, as an admin, I would like to go to the user's profile page and on the profile page there is a drop-down(only admin-accessible) and add the user to the group of my choice. How would I accomplish this? Through a type of form? A boolean field?

Comment: Can a user only belong to a single `SuperGroup` or can they belong to many different `SuperGroup`s?

Comment: Only one. I thought that I would just use a validation later. It's set up as a has_many so that they can belong to many, but I only did that for simplicity.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!